# Как String привести к List,и как передать значения из main в объект другого класса?

Tags: java

Как написать,чтобы хобби из String приводились к List и выводились без запятой с новой строки? И как переопределить метод toString?

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Введите имя: ");
        String name = scan.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Введите логин: ");
        String login = scan.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Введите возраст: ");
        byte age = scan.nextByte();
        System.out.println("Введите хобби через запятую");
        String hobby = scan.nextLine();



        User user = new User(name,login,age,hobby);

        try {
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("some.data");
            ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);


            oos.writeObject(user);

            oos.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("some.data");
            ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
            User user1 = (User) ois.readObject();
            System.out.println(user1);


            ois.close();
        }
        catch(IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch(ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

```
public class User{
    String name;
    String login;
    byte age;
    String hobby;

    User(){}

    User(String name,String login,byte age, List<String> hobby){
        this.name = name;
        this.login = login;
        this.age = age;
        this.hobby = hobby;


    }
        String[] hobbyArr = hobby.split(",");
        for(String a : hobbyArr)
            System.out.println(a);//не работает

    public String toString(){
        
    }
}
```

Comment: У Вас массив не получается к списку привести или что?

Comment: В классе Main String hobby принимает значение от пользователя через запятую и надо строку hobby,привести к List чтобы записать в конструктор класса User

Comment: а вот этот вот код: `String[] hobbyArr = hobby.split(","); for(String a : hobbyArr) System.out.println(a);//не работает`  он в принципе где находится... он у вас как то в воздухе между конструктором и методом `toString` весит

Comment: Строка `hobby` не может быть _приведена_ к типу `List`, её можно разбить при помощи `String::split` (как показано в коде), и преобразовать полученный массив в список например при помощи `Arrays.asList` или Stream API `Arrays.stream(hobby.split(",")).collect(Collectors.toList());`

Comment: вопрос еще такой: вам компилятор разрешает присваивать значение параметра `List<String> hobby` в поле `String hobby`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Реализовать *toString()* можно следующим образом**

```
    @Override
    public String toString() {
    return  getClass().getSimpleName() + 
            "{" +
            "name='" + name + '\'' +
            ", login='" + login + '\'' +
            ", age=" + age +
            ", hobby='" + hobby + '\'' +
            '}';
    }
```

Возвращает строковое представление объекта. В результате должно получиться краткое, но информативное представление, легко читаемое человеком. Рекомендуется, чтобы все подклассы переопределяли этот метод.

**Перевод хобби в *List***

```
    List<String> hobbies = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(hobby.split(",")));
```